# I can not do other work after calling URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession

I just want to hide imageview when the audio starts playing

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: serverUrl!) { [self] (data, res, error) in
            do {
                self.myMediaPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data!)
                self.myMediaPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
                self.myMediaPlayer1.delegate = self
                self.SetSessionPlayerOn()
                self.loading_img.isHidden = true    // not work til audio finish playing 
                print("imageview should be hidden now")
                self.myMediaPlayer1.play()
            }catch let error {
                print("error!!!!!!!!!!")
            }
        }.resume()
```

I can print atone but the image view will be hidden only when the media player has finished playing !

**UPDATE**
now it works. thanks ***Tushar***

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
                    self.loading_img.isHidden = true
                }
```

Comment: Put UI related task on main thread.

Comment: thanks. I did like in updated question. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should update the UI only on the main thread. So you have to add the below code inside dataTask. After that, you should update the layout of the view to update the UI. So the code should be like this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: serverUrl!) { [self] (data, res, error) in
        do {
            self.myMediaPlayer1 = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data!)
            self.myMediaPlayer1.prepareToPlay()
            self.myMediaPlayer1.delegate = self
            self.SetSessionPlayerOn()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.loading_img.isHidden = true
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                print("imageview should be hidden now")
            }
            self.myMediaPlayer1.play()
        }catch let error {
            print("error!!!!!!!!!!")
        }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: Good answer, except the `print("imageview should be hidden now")` should be inside the async call. When the print statement is invoked, the code to set `loading_img.isHidden=true` won't have executed yet.

Comment: You are right I didn't see the print there lol